# How to trigger action on route from controller in ember

Tags: ember.js, routes, action

Considering this example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hecewi/1/edit?html,js,output

The docs state that an action will be searched for on the controller first (which works in the example e.g. by pasting the `actions` hash into the `IndexController`), then on the current route and then along its parent routes until it hits `ApplicationRoute`. I'd expect the `testCamel` action in the example to be triggered then, but instead there is an error about the route did not get handled. How to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

The code to trigger an action is indeed correct. It's just an unfortunate chosen example. Since your route will initialize the controller, the route itself is probably not completely initialized by the time the action is sent. If you, for example, schedule the action to be triggered in the following run loop, it works perfect:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yaseva/1/edit